# Create a list which only can contain x items in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I want to create a list of `recentlyVisited`, which is a list limited to three items. Results older than the first three would be "pushed off" the edge of the list (and are completely irrelevant, so can be removed).

For a starting data type, say I have something like this.

```
{
  "username": "corvid",
  "recentlyVisited": ['1234', '5678', '1470']
}
```

Then, on submitting this question, I might do something like the following

```
Template.question.onCreated(function() {
  var questionId = Router.current().params._id;
  Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), {
    $push: { "recentlyVisited": questionId }
  });
});
```

I could publish it like this, but it still doesn't solve the core problem.

```
Meteor.publish('currentUser', function() {
  if(this.userId) {
    return Meteor.users.find(
      { _id: this.userId },
      { limit: { recentlyVisited: 3 } }
    );
  }
});
```

Is it possible to `$push` but limit the number that can be maintained in the set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible to $push but limit the number that can be maintained in
the set?**YES**

Use [$slice](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/slice/#up._S_slice) for this.

> The $slice modifier limits the number of array elements during a $push
> operation.
>
> This other quote cames from http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/
>
> For information on limiting the size of an array during an update with
> $push, see the $slice modifier instead

So just change the code a little bit like this.

```
Template.question.onCreated(function() {
  var questionId = Router.current().params._id;
  Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(),{$push:{
   recentlyVisited:{
    $each:[questionId ],
    $slice:3
    }
 }});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want the `$slice` operator.

```
Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), {
  $push: {
    recentlyVisited: {
      $each: [ questionId ],
      $position: 0,
      $slice: 3
    }  
  }
});
```

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/slice/